# django models - instance method to check if a model with matching attributes already exists in database

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0.8 and Python 3.5 in a project.

I want to write an instance method on class `Foo` that checks to ensure that a "similar record" (i.e. same attributes) does not exist in the database.

I am aware that I could use R.I (referential integrity) rules in the DB, to enforce this, but I want to push this responsibility to the model, not the DB layer.

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    # Model specific fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, null=False, default=1, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def is_available(self):
        return not models.Manager().get_queryset().filter(                                                                                       
                                    content_type=self.content_type,                                                     
                                    object_id=self.object_id, 
                                    user=self.user).exists()
```

My question is how to correctly implement the instance method `is_available()`. As it currently stands, when I invoke that method, I get the following error message (note Foo has been initialised correctly - omitted for sake of brevity):

```
>>> foo.is_available()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/project_base/myapp/models.py", line 57, in is_available
    user=self.user).exists()
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 836, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1253, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1277, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1153, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1015, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 284, in get_meta
    return self.model._meta
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback when including errors, so that it's clear where the error is occuring. The `filter()` method returns a queryset, so `temp is None` will never be `True`. Perhaps you want to could test `temp.exists()` instead.

Comment: Maybe also show what code you are using to call the method. Have you tried:
`return Foo.objects.filter(content_type=self.content_type, object_id=self.object_id, user=self.user).exists()` Also, I don't think you can just create a new Manager, how should it know which model you want the query to be associated with? It has to be assigned to a model property. (or simply use `Foo.objects`)

Comment: Question edited to reflect changes requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a generic `Manager()` to do this, because it will not have the context of the model that you're trying to query. You can just use the model's defined manager (`objects`) instead - something like this:

```
def is_available(self):
    return Foo.objects.filter(                                                                                       
        content_type=self.content_type,                                                     
        object_id=self.object_id, 
        user=self.user
    ).exists()
```

Note that doing this at the model level means you're not safe from race conditions, and it is still possible to end up saving "duplicate" objects to the database. Also,the result will change depending on whether the instance (`self`) has been saved or not - which might be an argument for doing this in a class method instead.